# Como simplificar a declaração dos tipos com Entity Frameowrk?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, code-first, migrations

Tenho algumas tabelas com vários campo do tipo datetime, e para todos eles preciso criar uma validação no OnModelCreating() para esse tipo, ou seja, preciso definir `.HasColumnType("datetime");`, minha duvida é;

Existem uma forma mais praticar para definir isso de alguma forma como um default?

Algo tipo;

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Usuarios>()
       .Property(so => so.Contains("dt)) // contem dt inicia dos campos datetime
       .HasColumnType("datetime");
```

---

A ideia e não ter que repetir esse monte de vezes como tive que fazer abaixo.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Usuarios>()
       .Property(so => so.dtAdmissao)
       .HasColumnName("dtAdmissao")
       .HasColumnType("datetime");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Usuarios>()
      .Property(so => so.dtInclusao)
      .HasColumnName("dtInclusao")
      .HasColumnType("datetime");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Usuarios>()
      .Property(so => so.dtNascimento)
      .HasColumnName("dtNascimento")
      .HasColumnType("datetime");

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Não é mais fácil parar de usar o Fluent como regra e começar a usar apenas quando for muito necessário?

Comment: @jbueno, não sei, como seria isso? tem algum exemplo?

Comment: É só não fazer esse *mapping*. O EF mapeia automaticamente. Ainda mais que você tá criando as colunas com o mesmo nome das propriedades. Fazer esse *mapping* acaba sendo só perda de tempo.

Comment: @jbueno, sim, mas tentei fazer sem usar o .HasColumnType("datetime"); e tive problema com o banco de dados na hora de fazer o insert.

Comment: Sobre aquela pergunta de ontem? O problema deve ser outro, né.

Comment: @jbueno, Em relação a essa pergunta sim... mas na de ontem na hora de salvar se eu não declarasse da forma acima dava erro no insert. só que ficou chato ter que fazer isso para todas as classes do modelo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma de deixar uma configuração ***global*** para o `Entity Framework` é no método `OnModelCreating` com a linha

> `modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(x => x.HasColumnType("datetime"));`

Segue o código:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(x => x.HasColumnType("datetime"));
}
```

<sub>**Observação:** pode ser feito também para outros tipos.</sub>

**Outro exemplo de configuração**

Crie uma classe e faça herança com [`Convention`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.conventionsconfiguration(v=vs.113).aspx) e no seu `Construtor` escreve o mesmo código de configuração da coluna [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
public class DateTimeConvention : Convention
{
    public DateTimeConvention()
    {
        this.Properties<DateTime>()
            .Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime"));        
    }
}
```

No `OnModelCreating` trabalhe com convenção da seguinte forma:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{   
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new DateTimeConvention());
}
```

---

**Alguns exemplos adicionais:**

Configurando o tamanho da coluna:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
                .Configure(c => c.HasMaxLength(500));
```

Configurando o tamanho da coluna para uma determinado nome de coluna:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
                .Where(x => x.Name == "Name")
                .Configure(c => c.HasMaxLength(250));
```

***Referencias:***

- [Introducing Custom Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819164(v=vs.113).aspx)
- [ConventionsConfiguration Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.conventionsconfiguration(v=vs.113).aspx)
- [Convention Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.convention(v=vs.113).aspx)
- [System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions(v=vs.113).aspx)
- [Estrutura DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Custom Code-First Conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/custom-conventions-codefirst.aspx)

Comment: Isso ficar global para qualquer classe certo?

Comment: Isso @MarconcilioSouza, funciona muito bem isso inclusive e não precisa configurar nas demais. Já utilizei. Nos links também tem citação reafirmando tudo isso.

Comment: vlw, era isso mesmo que precisava.